# Can two different share servers residing on the same server connect to the same repository?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm trying to connect a second share UI on the same server (different container) to connect to the same repository (which resides on a different server) as another share instance. Is this possible because I haven't managed to be able to connect the second thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. In general you can hook as many share instances to one repository as you want unless the share apps require mutually exclusive repo configuration for some special reason. It does not really matter on how many nodes or containers they are deployed.  Just make sure the repository endpoints are configured correctly.

You may need to tweak hazelcast configuration to see things coherently though. Check http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fhazelcast-cluster-share.html for the details.